# Papersize option in geometry package is misbehaving. Potential conflict with other packages?

Tags: hyperref, memoir, geometry, paper-size

I'm trying to set a custom paper size for my document via the `geometry` package. However, whenever I add the [papersize={x,y}] option, I get the wrong output. The document compiles successfully (with XeLaTeX), but the page size is not change, and additionally the margins appear all messed up (text flows past the bottom margin).

This doesn't happen on a fresh document, so I suspect the geometry package is in conflict with one of the other packages I'm using; but I can't figure out which one.

Here's a my code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{memoir}

%set page dimensions
\usepackage[
xetex,
outer=1.84in,inner=0.92in, 
top=0.92in, bottom=2.1in,
papersize={8.27in,13.39in}]{geometry}

%Set English lang. 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

%enable emphasis with color instead of italics
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ecol}{gray}{0.15}
\renewcommand\emph[1]{\textcolor{ecol}{\textbf{#1}}}

%define typeface
\usepackage{fontspec}[ligatures=tex]
\setmainfont{Baskerville}[SmallCapsFont = Bodoni 72 Smallcaps]%

\usepackage{microtype}

%figures and graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}

%layout debugging
\usepackage{layout}

%for referencing labels
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, anchorcolor=red]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Any ideas as to what might be causing the issue?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384945/geometry-parameters-not-working-on-windows-but-working-on-mac. You need to set `\setstocksize` too. The problem in your example is triggered by colorlinks as it loads color which loads the graphic-drivers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. As for the duplicate - the two questions have related answers, but I don't see how they're duplicate. Either way, thanks for the answer. I'm relatively new to using the memoir package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one discovers by trimming your example, and after adding `setpagesize=false` option to hyperref, there is something fishy happening when `colorlinks` option is also used.

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{memoir}
%\documentclass{article}

%set page dimensions
\usepackage[
%xetex,
outer=1.84in,inner=0.92in, 
top=0.92in, bottom=2.1in,
papersize={8.27in,13.39in}
]{geometry}

%Set English lang. 
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{english}

%enable emphasis with color instead of italics
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\definecolor{ecol}{gray}{0.15}
%\renewcommand\emph[1]{\textcolor{ecol}{\textbf{#1}}}

%define typeface
%\usepackage{fontspec}[ligatures=tex]
%\setmainfont{Baskerville}[SmallCapsFont = Bodoni 72 Smallcaps]%

%\usepackage{microtype}

%figures and graphics
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage{wrapfig}
% \usepackage{caption}

%layout debugging
%\usepackage{layout}

%for referencing labels
\usepackage[setpagesize=false, 
            colorlinks=true, 
            %anchorcolor=red
]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

With `colorlinks=true` commented out, one gets this

[image]

But with `colorlinks=true` active, one gets this

[image]

I don't know as of now what causes this. I also tested with user (not lipsum) paragraphs just to make sure there was not some weird interaction between `hyperref` and `lipsum`. It happens the same with normal non-lipsum generated text.

As you are using `memoir` class, I presume you have read its documentation hence perhaps try to use its own interface for page layout. (not tested)

The trimmed example can also be compiled with pdflatex with same result. It is not xetex specific. Don't pass xetex option to geometry, it knows that.

---

You might want to report to `memoir` maintainer

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[papersize={10cm,25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[setpagesize=false,
            colorlinks=true
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

displays the problem. It goes away by commenting `colorlinks=true`. Using the `article` class or `book` class, no problem.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[papersize={10cm,25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[setpagesize=false,
            colorlinks=true
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

---

When using latex to examine the dvi, one finds in the `colorlinks=true` case (memoir class, 10cm and 25cm) the following in dvi

```
papersize=614.295pt,794.96999pt papersize=284.52756pt,711.3189pt papersize=614.295pt,794.96999pt
```

where I removed some non-ascii bytes.

With `colorlinks=false` or no option one sees at same location sort of in dvi:

```
papersize=614.295pt,794.96999pt papersize=284.52756pt,711.3189pt
```

Seems that `colorlinks=true` option of `hyperref` triggers a nother page setting special, but this happens with `memoir` not with `article`.

---

---

It seems that the problem is fixed simply by loading  `geometry` **after** `hyperref`. (and `setpagesize=false` is then unneeded)

But I did not invest the time into debugging the root cause of the (existing) issue `memoir` + `hyperref` + `geometry`.

---

---

As explained by @UlrikeFischer (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384952/4686 and her comment), with `colorlinks=true` the `color` package is loaded which in turn triggers usage of the graphics provided drivers.

The driver is now `memoir` aware and uses `\stockwidth` and `\stockheight` but `geometry` did no modify these lengths.

(with pdftex driver, executed at begin document)

```
  \ifdim\stockwidth>0pt\relax
    \ifdim\stockheight>0pt\relax
      \pdfpagewidth=\stockwidth
      \pdfpageheight=\stockheight
    \fi
  \fi
```

Thus `hyperref` is out of the loop, the following MWE triggers the issue as well:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[papersize={10cm,10cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}% or color package

\listfiles

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

The `setpagesize=false` option of `hyperref` is without effect because it does not influence the effect of loading the graphics provided drivers after `geometry`.

As I recommended above the way is to use rather the `memoir` user interface, (this is also @daleif and @UlrikeFischer recommendations, Ulrike said in a comment:

> The recommendation in my answer is to explicitly set
>   `\setstocksize{<width>}{<height>}`. But David will hopefully update
>   geometry so that this is no longer necessary in the future.

)

or load `geometry` last or load `color` first and use `setpagesize=false` if hyperref is last.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[papersize={10cm,10cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[setpagesize=false,
           colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

has correct output *and now `setpagesize=false` has an effect and is needed*. So you can fix the issue by loading `color` early. Or better as said, use `memoir` own interface to page dimensions.

Comment: BTW I don't see any difference with geometry + hyperref with out without `colorlinks` option. Both give strange result.

Comment: @daleif, I trust you on this... results looked ok to me without `colorlinks=true` or with `colorlinks=false` or with `geometry` after `hyperref`...

Comment: I just had it running with an auto updating pdf viewer. Apparently hyperref let the default stock size from memoir override the paper size given by geometry, and uses that for the paper size.

Comment: @daleif but it is strange that `setpagesize=false` remains without effect with hyperref (must go now...)

Comment: I just did a full update, `setpagesize=false` for hyperref seems to work

Comment: @daleif full update changed nothing for me with pdftex.

Comment: The recommendation in my answer is to explicitly set `\setstocksize{<width>}{<height>}`. But David will hopefully update geometry so that this is no longer necessary in the future.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I moved your comment to the body of my answer.

Comment: @jfbu I've added some images of what I see.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I will use memoir's native commands; I only use geometry out of habit (which on the doc it recommends using the option 'xetex'). I tried to alter the page's dimensions via the \setlength command, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @johnymm the `geometry` doc does not recommend using option `xetex` it says precisely `By default, geometry guesses the driver appropriate to the system in use. Therefore, you don't have to set a driver in most cases. However, if you want to use dvipdfm, you should specify it explicitly.` This means that you don't really need `xetex` option.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused, because at the preface of the document where it introduces the driver it says "To set xetex is strongly recommended with XeLaTeX." Am I misinterpreting that sentence?

Comment: You are right about that sentence on first page. But the sentence is misleading:check the log and you will see `*geometry* driver: auto-detecting` `*geometry* detected driver: xetex`.

Comment: I think that sentence referred to obsolete usage of a `geometry.cfg` in TeXLive  which used `pdftex` driver. But these comments are obsolete, nowadays the file at `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.cfg` is completely commented out.

Comment: This doc dates back probably to at least [`8 years ago`](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2919.1266100191.20360.ctan-ann@dante.de). Maintenance moved over to @DavidCarlisle this year, doc not yet updated I presume.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably say it is an issue with `geometry` + `hyperref` vs `memoir`. Rather than a direct `memoir` issue.

It works just fine, if you use the memoir layout interface instead of `geometry`

```
\setstocksize{13.39in}{8.27in}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.92in}{1.84in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.92in}{2.1in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]
```

See the `memoir` manual for an explanation for `fixed`, I'd problably use `nearest` instead.

---

Just as a comment to @jfbu

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[
papersize={10cm,20cm},
]{geometry}
\usepackage[
setpagesize=false
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Gives (pdfinfo)

```
Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.19
CreationDate:   Thu Oct 18 14:37:39 2018
ModDate:        Thu Oct 18 14:37:39 2018
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          9
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      283.465 x 566.929 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      33104 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

Image (via Evince)

[image]

And

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[
papersize={10cm,20cm},
]{geometry}
\usepackage[
%setpagesize=false
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}

Creator:        LaTeX with hyperref
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.19
CreationDate:   Thu Oct 18 14:40:31 2018
ModDate:        Thu Oct 18 14:40:31 2018
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          9
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page rot:       0
File size:      33115 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

Image:

[image]

Everything using TeXLive 2018, fully updated

Comment: Thanks for the posted images: I get same as yours, it means using `setpagesize=false` works as expected, and that was my experience. When I said it did not work, it was in the context of the `colorlinks` options.... (sorry for possibly not having been clear about the context of "`setpagesize=false` does not work")