Interference between color and geometry packages under memoir class
I have the following extra simple code (which I trimmed from larger code):
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[paperheight=150mm,
            paperwidth=100mm
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
    \textcolor{red}{Brother}.
\end{document}

It looks like the color package is interfering with geometry when using memoir document type. I just can't figure out why and how to fix it.
The resulting page is printed on the top left corner, and the majority of the page is empty:


Can you specify what you mean by "interfering"? Is the result not what you expect?

(I was under the impression that memoir had its own methods to change the page geometry)

Sorry! I have updated my question..

Change the order in which you load the packages

Oh thanks! It was fixed if I switch the locations of color and geometry.. But why does it behave like this?

counter question: why do you use geometry with memoir?

Well, in addition to paper size, geometry allows me to accurately define top,left,right,bottom margins (which include required bleed amount). I could never figure out how to produce the same results with memoir alone.

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455641/36296 for some background information

From the page sam points to \setstocksize{150mm}{100mm} \settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*} \setlrmarginsandblock{15mm}*1 \setulmarginsandblock{15mm}*1 \checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

geometry doesn't change the memoir length \stockwidth and \stockheight, and that confuses color and it picks up the wrong page size.
